# iPhone - Change colors dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uicolor

I have a meter as shown in the figure. I can able to move the needle across the meter, no problem with that. The problem is, I need to change the color codes in the meter dynamically according to the user input.

I am getting three values from the user. If the first value is 30, I need to set green color in the range 0 to 30. If the second value is 70, I need to set yellow color till the range 70. Similarly for the third value, I need to set the maximum value and the set the red color. 
[image]

Changing the color code of a view is not a big deal. But, I have no idea how to dynamically set the colors in a particular range(irregular shape).

**Edited:** Currently I am just moving the needle across the meter (Moving an imageview inside a normal UIView). Expected output should be like the image attached and I had not set any colors now.

Help me to proceed. Thanks in advance..!

Comment: How are you setting the colors now? Are you using UIView with rounded corners? Or UIImageView?

Comment: are you talking about gradients?

Comment: You need to provide us with more information than this. How are you currently drawing the meter? Is it a static image that you are displaying, or are you generating the image in code?

Comment: if you will not get any answer then just do one thing...make different different image and set this images to view according to your  pin move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the most simplest way, would be -

Add 3 separate UIView layers to parent UIView layer.

all these 3 subview layers will have different colors - which can be dynamically changed.

These subviews, are just plain rectangles.

Now - this is where the fun begins:

You must rotate and position each subview separately - accordingly how it should be.

It also can be done dynamically, but it will be a bit harder.

Just follow these tutorials to rotate UIView:

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4181-rotating-an-uiimageview-around-an-arbitrary-point.html

[Rotate a UIImageView around a point off screen? (center of uiImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162374/rotate-a-uiimageview-around-a-point-off-screen-center-of-uiimageview)

[rotate UIView/UITableView around a point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102632/rotate-uiview-uitableview-around-a-point)

[How to rotate view around anchor point multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307083/how-to-rotate-view-around-anchor-point-multiple-times)

And at the end - mask parent UIView, so that all subviews would be trimmed and appeared as irregular shapes.

Here is a tutorial how to do it:
[How to mask an image in IOS sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872975/how-to-mask-an-image-in-ios-sdk)

Good luck!